# SDL Trados Alternative

Tags: gratis, open-source

I am looking for an alternative for [SDL Trados](https://www.sdl.com/software-and-services/translation-software/sdl-trados-studio/) with the following requirements:

- Free
- Run on Mac OSX and Linux

Current alternatives are:

- OmegaT

However, I am preferably after an Open-Source alternative. For those unsure, Trados [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SDL_Trados_Studio):

> SDL Trados Studio is a computer-assisted translation software
>   suite,[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SDL_Trados_Studio) a successor to the older Translators Workbench originally
>   developed by the German company Trados GmbH and currently available
>   from SDL plc, a provider of customer experience cloud solutions. It is
>   considered the market leader[3] in providing translation software
>   across the entire translation supply chain, including freelance
>   translators, language service providers, corporate language
>   departments and academic institutions.

Comment: Can you specify any requirements for such a software? Like whatr should it do and what features you expect?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Did you try Heartsome Translation Studio? I must say it's been discontinued.

Comment: " I am preferably after an Open-Source alternative" - really? Do you intend to modify the code? Or do you just mean that you don't want to pay for it? In which case, use the [tag:gratis] tag

Comment: I would like it to be free and Open-source if possible, but free for sure.  If Heartsome Translation Studio has been discontinued, I have no interest in that then. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: The most important feature I expect is Multilingual Translation Memory. I am also interested in the ability to transform excel glossaries into term bases. To that end, I'm using another software (glossary converter) for the time being. Being unfamiliar with any other software, feel free to suggest some.